# Any recommendations for good books on general topology?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am looking for books that are on general set theory. So open sets, closed sets, Boundarys complements etc. I sort of understand most of the logic but I would love to go deeper into it.

Comment: This is general topology, not set theory.

Comment: Munkres' book is great for a beginner to general topology.

Comment: I can recommend the excellent book by [Dugundji](https://books.google.at/books/about/Topology.html?id=FgFRAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y).